# In Ruby, is there a way for classes to be accesible by package, or are all of the classes to be written in the same file of code?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, netbeans-6.9

I'm using Netbeans to program in Ruby and I can't seem to access other classes I write from the main class in Ruby until I place that code inside the main class itself. Is there a way to fix this so that it works like Java classes do?

Comment: Do you basically mean, what is the Ruby version of `import`?

Comment: Yes, if that includes importing classes (that you write) from the same package that main file is in

Comment: This question would have been easily answered by reading through any of the many Ruby tutorials on the web. http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book/ might be a good starting point for you, or http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/ or http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/to-ruby-from-java/

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you are looking to `import` a class you wrote in a separate file into your current file. If this is what you are looking to do, take a look at [`require_relative`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)

```
# cow.rb
class Cow
  def moo
    'Moooooooo'
  end
end

# main.rb
require_relative 'cow.rb'

milford = Cow.new
puts milford.moo #=> 'Moooooooo'
```

Things to look out for is that `require_relative` searches for the file in the current location of the file you call it in. For instance:

```
# If cow.rb is in folder 'animals'
require_relative 'animals/cow.rb' #=> Fine
require_relative 'cow.rb' #=> LoadError
```

I would suggest finding some good tutorials on Ruby or finding a beginners book. Some of them are even available online like [Programming Ruby The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/). This question covers some pretty basic Ruby concepts.

Also, I would not suggest using Netbeans since they cut out their support for Ruby. This is fine if you want to continue to use the old version of Netbeans but you will soon find it lacking support for newer Ruby versions.

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, Ruby has no concept of "packages". There are files, and modules. To import all of the global variables, constants, modules, and classes from a file in the same directory, type:

```
require_relative "myfile.rb"
```

You can now use any classes, modules, constants, and global variables defined in `myfile.rb` in your code.